# How to set up locales in Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, locale

## Description

I have a node.js app deployed in Heroku and I want to set up more locales than default ones in Heroku. Why? Because I need to save the date in es_ES and Heroku only provides en_EN.

### What I already tried:

(Following their official documentation: [Heroku locales](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-locale))

1. heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-locale
2. Create in my app root, a file called ".locales" filled with "es_ES"
3. Purged cache app on Heroku
4. Deployed the app to Heroku
5. In the log it's shown that the language pack is detected and downloaded

```
remote: === Updating or installing language-pack-es-base
remote: Get:1 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg InRelease [41.4 kB]
remote: Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]
remote: Get:3 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg/main amd64 Packages [255 kB]
remote: Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
remote: Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
remote: Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages [11.3 MB]
remote: Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [1344 kB]
remote: Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [324 kB]
remote: Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [486 kB]
remote: Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1213 kB]
remote: Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [826 kB]
remote: Fetched 16.2 MB in 3s (5727 kB/s)
remote: Reading package lists...
remote: Reading package lists...
remote: Building dependency tree...
remote: The following additional packages will be installed:
remote:   language-pack-es
remote: The following NEW packages will be installed:
remote:   language-pack-es language-pack-es-base
remote: 0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 31 not upgraded.
remote: Need to get 2847 kB of archives.
remote: After this operation, 12.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
remote: Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 language-pack-es-base all 1:18.04+20180712 [2845 kB]
remote: Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 language-pack-es all 1:18.04+20180712 [1904 B]
remote: Fetched 2847 kB in 1s (3437 kB/s)
remote: Download complete and in download only mode
remote: === Unpacking and configuring all locales
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 57.9M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v161
```

## Current result

Executing 'heroku run "locale -a"' I got this output

```
Running locale -a on ⬢ my-super-secret-app... up, run.2545 (Free)
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
```

## Expected

To have the language pack es_ES available in order to use it when I want to generate a Date. I have already tried with javascript Date object and currently I'm using moment.js but no one is working.

Any advice?

Comment: I'm in the same situation but with pt_BR, so far none of the suggested solutions seem to work. Have you managed to find a way?